# Multiply 3d * 2d element by element

Tags: python, numpy

Hello I'm trying to weight a serie of images over a matrix of coefficients.

Is there a way to escape a for and do it quickly?

```
for i in range(0, shape.mbn[2])
    mbn_eq[:,:,i] = mbn[:,:,i] .* coeff_n;
```

mbn_eq is a serie of images m*n *i and coeff_n is matrix of coefficients

Let's say mbn

```
{[1,1], [1,1];
[2,2], [2,2];}
```

this would be the coeff_n matrix

```
{[1,2], [3,4]}
```

so the result I want would be

```
{[1,2], [3,4];
[2,4], [6,8]}
```

Comment: Could you add a small data sample, along with the expected output?

Comment: Added a small example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy arrays, they support [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) behind the scenes.

```
import numpy as np 

mbn = np.array([[1,1],[1,1],[2,2],[2,2]])
mbn = mbn.reshape(2,2,2)
print(mbn)
print(mbn.shape)
coeff = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])

print(mbn * coeff)
```

Comment: I think it should be `mbn * coeff[:, :, np.newaxis]`, which would broadcast along a new inner dimension. `mbn * coeff` would broadcast along a new outer dimension, but the loop suggest that each value along the inner dimension of `mbn` should be multiplied by a copy of `coeff` (unfortunately the example is not very clear because the shapes are `(2, 2, 2)` and `(2, 2)`, and `mbn` has only two different values).

Comment: `print(mbn * coeff[:,:,np.newaxis])` seems to print out an incorrect output (if the example is valid) when i try it. It produces `[ [[1,1], [2,2]] , [[6,6], [8,8]] ]` @jdehesa

Comment: Ah you're right, the question is a bit confusing but it's probably like you say then.